# WiFi adapter is not recognised by Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel

I have an Asus X555LB which has Mediatek MT7630E wifi adapter. I can see that it is Unclaimed, so Ubuntu does detect it but it does not have drivers. 
I have followed quite a lot of solutions online but none worked.

[neurobin/MT7630E](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E)

I have cloned and tried installing the driver from the link above, as suggested by most users. But it seems that this issue was resolved for only Kernel v3.x (Ubuntu 16.04). It is still not working for Ubuntu 18.04 since it has Kernel v4.15 (That is my assumption).

I have also checked `rfkill list` and that is empty.

```
lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
```

Is there any other suggestion you can give me? Or how to raise this issue?

Note: Ubuntu 18.04 is dual-booted with Win10